# How marginal contributions of adding a variable in a model is calculated in determining SHAP feature importance?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, shap, feature-importances

I was trying to find feature importance using SHAP values in python for Isolation Forest. SHAP calculates the feature importance of a feature($i$) pertaining to a model($f$) for a datapoint(**$x$**) using the following formula:
[image]

where N is the set of all features. Now, the terms within the summation contain $[f_x(S\bigcup\{i\}) - f_x(S)]$ where $S$ is a set of features that does not contain the feature $i$ (i.e $S \subseteq N$ \ $\{i\}$).

So, for example, if we have features $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ in our model and we want to find the importance of feature 4 ($i=4$), then the term  $[f_x(S\bigcup\{i\}) - f_x(S)]$ could be $[f_x(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) - f_x(x_1, x_2, x_3)]$ or $[f_x(x_1, x_4) - f_x(x_1)]$ etc.

So, we fit or model $f_x$ (linear regression or decision tree or whatever it is) on all the features and get the value $f_x(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ as the prediction of the fitted model at x. But how do we calculate the other terms, for example $f_x(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. It is written in many articles that $f_x(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ could be calculated by fitting the same model "as if the feature $x_4$ were not present". But that would be computationally too heavy. How does python's `shap` package calculate those terms?